# Attaching disks and contracting is equivalent to taking quotients.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space, cw-complexes, mobius-band

Take a Mobius band $M$ and attached a disk $D^2$ along its boundary, which is a copy of $S^1$ embedded in $M$. It is known that what we obtain is something homeomorphic to the projective plane. Now the quotient $M/\partial M$ is also homeomorphic to the projective plane.

> Are these two operations "equivalent"? More specifically, attaching a disk $D^2$ to a space $X$ and then contracting $D^2$ to a point is equivalent to taking the quotient of $X$ by $S^1$?

Comment: You have to make precise what you want to know. I guess that you assume that you have an *embedded copy* of $S^1$ in $X$ and then attach $D^2$ to this copy.

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Then you should add this information to your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost done.